# Power Query, avg value based on the values appearing within a specified date range

Tags: powerquery, date-range, m

Context:

I have a data set for the weights of truck and trailer combinations coming into my site over the span of a few years. I have organized my data by seasons as I am trying to prove that the truck:trailers in winter are noticeably heavier due to ice, snow, and mud. The theory is, if the tare weight is higher in this season (the weight of the truck after it empties its load)  than its Avg tare weight (which I need to calculate from the data) it can be deduced that the truck:trailer combinations are coming in with extra weight that we pay for in part as some snow/ice/mud falls off in the trailer emptying process.

What I've done so far:

- I've defined a custom date range for my seasons
- I've grouped Truck:Trailer by: count to get a duplicates column and, all rows to keep all my details

  - I've filtered out every combination I've seen less than 50 times, as i want good representation for each truck:trailer combo so that I can better emphasize repeated patterns
  - I've added an index column to better keep track of the individuals before expanding the details

What I need to do:

- I only want to work with truck:trailer combinations which have weighed in for all four seasons at least once
- I need to find the average tare weight of the truck:trailer combinations based over the extended range for both summer and autumn (the dry time of the year) while preserving the raw tare data for all seasons, as I need to eventually compare the winter tare values to this average.

[example of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQWGr.png)

When I'm finished I'd like the data to look something like this

[Pivot Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQWGr.png)

[query data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNHzX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question (all seasons) you can add a column that holds the distinct count of the values in [Season] for each [Driver:Trailer]. Then filter your table on that column, keeping only the 4's. To achieve this, add the following m-code to your script in the Advanced Editor. Change the part after `in` to `#"DistinctCount Season"`

```
#"DistinctCount Season" = Table.Join(#"insert name previous step","Driver:Trailer",
    Table.Group(#"insert name previous step", {"Driver:Trailer"}, 
    {{"DistinctCountSeasons", each Table.RowCount(Table.Distinct(_,"Season")),
    type number}}),"Driver:Trailer")
```

Insert the name of your previous step where indicated.

---

For second question:

You can use a matrix-visual for that in you report. First create a measure:

```
[AverageTare] = AVERAGE(table'[Tare])
```

Then put `[Season]` on Rows and the `[AverageTare]` on Values. You can create a group (right-click on [Season] in the FIELDS-pain) called [DrySeason], to combine the values for Spring and Summer.
If that doesn't work for you, explore the AVERAGEX function.

**EDIT** 
In excel you can use a pivottable. Put [Season] on Rows and the [AverageTare] on Values. Right-click a value in the pivottable. Select `Value Field Setting` and choose `Average`. Then select the Seasons you want to group, right-click and select `Group`.

**EDIT 2** 
To add a column in the Power Query Editor that holds the average [Tare] for the [Season] in each row, add the following steps to your script in the Avanced Editor:

```
#"GroupedSeasonAvg" = Table.Group(#"Insert name previous step", {"Season"}, {{"AVG", each List.Average([Tare]), type number}}),
#"JoinOnSeason" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Insert name previous step",{"Season"},GroupedSeasonAvg,{"Season"},"AVGGrouped"),
#"ExtractSeasonAVG" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(JoinOnSeason, "AVGGrouped", {"AVG"}, {"SeasonAVG"})
```

It works something like this:

1. `"GroupedSeasonAvg"` : Creates a table with the avereges for each [Season]
2. `"JoinOnSeason"`: Creates a new column with tables joining the [Season] value for each row to [Season] in the grouped table.
3. `#"ExtractSeasonAVG"`: Expand each table and keep only [AVG].

Comment: The first part worked great, but I'm a little confused by the second part. I'm not quite sure what you mean by create a measure, I haven't done that in power query before. I did a little search and that looks like a power BI function. Is that what you used? I'm still fairly green with power query and I haven't touched Power BI yet. Do I need to install power BI to do this?

Comment: I assumed you were in Power BI because that's how you tagged the Question. You can also use a pivottable in Excel. See my edit.

Comment: That works but it's a little restricting. Is there a way to do this in power query or get the info from the pivot table back into the query? I'm hoping to display this [average] as separate column for each distinct row value for  Driver:trailer. this then evolves into creating a [Difference] column = [Tare]-[Avg], finally leading to a conditional column where I test to see if the difference is above or below 1000lbs [Logic]. my final chart has [index] and [season] in the rows. I'll edit my question to include an illustration.

Comment: See edit 2. With this calculated column you should be able do achieve what you want.

Comment: I figured ended up figuring it all out but you did help me get there. Here are the steps I did.

Comment: I duplicated my query and created a conditional column in which I grouped summer and Autumn together as the dry season and then grouped this column with [Driver:trailer] averaging tare. I filter the conditional column for the dry season and then deleted that column. I then merged this query with my original, merging by [driver:trailer]. thanks again!